# How to split an object into two different

Tags: modeling, texturing, objects

I`ve created an UFO and when it came to texturing I encountered a problem. I`ve made this object of default cube so basically these two parts are a one object, so texturing works fo both of them. How can I divide it to two different objects (like body and glass)? Thank you.

[image: the object]

Comment: you need to assign a different material to each part, go in the Properties panel > Material, create new materials, select the faces you want, click on the Assign button under the materials list